# Run background thread before UITableView Segues

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uitableview

I have a UITableView that shows a list of Movies. (Movie name and ID are stored in an pre-populated array).

When I click a row, I want to the app to go into the background BEFORE segueing, download the "movie info" AND THEN segue to the new view once the background thread has finished. The downloading of the information works fine, so I have left out that part of the code.

However, I can't seem to get my logic right on how to show the spinner to let the user know something is going on and then transition or fail upon the background completion.

Any help?

**In my UITableViewController class**

```
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
        MovieDetailsViewController *mvc = (MovieDetailsViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        mvc.movie = movie;
    }

    - (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender  {
    //I KNOW THAT IF THIS RETURNS TRUE prepareForSegue is called 
    bool canSegue = NO:
        if ([identifier containsString:@"seg_movie"]) {

            // SHOW Activity spinner

              [self doMovieLookup];

                if (movie != nil) {
                    canSegue = YES;
                } 
        }
        return canSegue;

    }



- (void) doMovieLookup {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //HERE I AM COMMUNCATING WITH THE SERVER AND PARSING JSON RESULTS INTO A DICTIONARY 
        //this code works fine then I send the JSON results on to object creation.
        [self buildMovieWithDictionary:[[dictionaryResults objectForKey:@"Movie"] objectAtIndex:0]];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

          //DO I NEED SOMETHING HERE?

          //STOP SPINNER

        });

    });

}
```

**Just an method that creates the Movie object incase anyone was curios.**

```
- (void) buildMovieWithDictionary : (NSDictionary*) dictionary {
    movie = [[Movie alloc] init];
    movie.title  = [dictionary objectForKey:@"MovieTitle"];  
    movie.description  = [dictionary objectForKey:@"MovieTitle"];   
    movie.releasedate  = [dictionary objectForKey:@"MovieTitle"];       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but a bit out of order I think.  Instead of calling `doMovieLookup` in `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`, try doing it in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Then, you can call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` where you make your `dispatch_async` call back to the main thread.

Comment: Thanks! For those coming to this thread in the future, in IB I removed the segue from the cell, and made a segue from the View Controller to the new Destination View Controller then used Wyatt's performSegueWithIdentifer suggestion.